# What the difference between these generics statements?

Tags: java, generics

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

and

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap();
```

As it's new to me, I am not sure what is the actual difference between these two statements, as both seems to work fine. I tried to find elsewhere but couldn't find any specific answers.

Comment: I think this is related to new functionality in Java 7. Previously you had to use the first example now the second <String, Integer> is implied by the first.

Comment: The second line throws a warning about using a raw type.

Comment: @onesixtyfourth no, the diamond operator is explicitly written. The code would be: `Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();`.

Comment: The second one will give you a warning as you have not specified the type held in the map.  Keep in mind, the way generics were implemented in Java, the type safety is lost at runtime.  In essence, it's just a hint to the compiler to keep you from doing something dumb, but it doesn't prevent it from happening.

Comment: @CodeChimp that could be an answer.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza ah maybe thats why I never got it to work then. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second variant uses a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html), which is generally bad. In fact, raw types only exist for reasons of backwards compatibility.

Consider this:

```
Map<Double, Double> other = new HashMap<Double, Double>();
other.put(42.0, 42.0);

Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap(other);
```

Using raw types, we've managed to put doubles into a map between strings and integers!

We can't do this with the properly parametrized type:

```
Map<Double, Double> other = new HashMap<Double, Double>();
other.put(42.0, 42.0);

Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>(other);  // error
```

Answer (score 3):

The second one will give you a warning as you have not specified the type held in the map. Keep in mind, the way generics were implemented in Java, the type safety is lost at runtime. In essence, it's just a hint to the compiler to keep you from doing something dumb, but it doesn't prevent it from happening.

Note: Made an answer and the behest of Luiggi Mendoza.

Comment: Mine wasn't a behest, just an advice

Answer (score 0):

In the first case,the map will always provide compile type safety.
The second one is an unchecked conversion from a pre-generics map to map of type `Map<String, Integer>.`The 2nd statement could be dangerous considering that the map may not contain String as key and Integer as value,it may as well contain simple objects of type `java.lang.Object or any other Object` and when your code treats them as String or Integer ,it will burst into exception

Answer (score 0):

From the Java people, as written in [Generic TypeInterface Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)

> Note that to take advantage of type inference during generic class
>   instantiation, you must use the diamond. In the following example, the
>   compiler generates an unchecked conversion warning because the
>   HashMap() constructor refers to the HashMap raw type, not the 
>   `Map<String, List<String>>` type:
>
> ```
> Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap(); // unchecked conversion warning
> ```

That means you are creating reference myMap of `<String, List<String>>` type and assigning `HashMap` Object to that reference of **raw** type.